# "nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found" when starting hostapd

Tags: broadcom, hostapd

I have been trying to get my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop to make an access point to connect my blackberry playbook . hostapd gave error

```
    Configuration file: ./hostapd-minimal.conf
    nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
    nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

Is this a BCM4312 problem? Can madwifi , hostap create wifi acccess point for me?
Connectify can do this on windows so is there no equivalent??

Comment: Okay After a lot of searching turned this up.If you have a broadcom network controller Check if your card is compatible with b43. If it is awesome and keep reading.
The default Broadcom sta driver (wl) will not support access point mode. So install b43 taking precautionary measure to be online by any means necessary. Turn it on using modprobe. Now follow instructions and try to set up access point. 
(http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43)
(http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=91991.0)

Comment: BCM 4312 is the network controller right? Even I want to establish an AP using hostapd, but am stuck at where you are...! When I try to install firmware-b43-installer, i get an error message saying " Not supported low power chip 14e4:4315 " and fails to install! Did you encounter such an issue, is it enough to install b43-fwcutter ? I am a lot confused... THanks for posting on this topic
Sudharshan

Comment: Final answer:
Follow either of the suggestions on 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/105217/how-do-i-create-a-non-adhoc-wifi-hotspot/118208#118208

Comment: @Sudharshan I got it working a couple of days back, follow it up with this post. I have posted all that worked for me in the above comment.

Comment: Have you disable the Network Manager Service?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should edit `/etc/hostapd.conf` and change `driver=nl80211` to `madwifi`.